# How to catch AuthenticationError?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

I have following singup server function. When i pass wrong login and password obviosly i get error. In my react app i observed in console following message:Uncaught (in promise) Error:Authentication Error.

Of course i show message for user but should i avoid "Uncought" case in console and how, becouse to be honest i have no idea how to use catch here?

```
  signIn: async (parent, {username,email,password},{models}) => {
        if (email){
            email = email.trim().toLowerCase()
        }
        const user = await models.User.findOne({
            $or: [{email},{username}]
        });
  
        //user not found
        if(!user){
            throw new AuthenticationError('Authentication Error')
        }

        const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
        //console.log(valid)
        if(!valid){
            throw new AuthenticationError('Authentication Error')
        }

        //Creation token and return
        return jwt.sign({id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try a simple Try-Catch in the call of the signIn function?

```
try{
   ...
   signIn(....)
   ...
}catch(Exception e) {
  //console.log(e) ->should be 'Authentication error'
  //Block of code to handle errors
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).